# How to add a new .py file using Tkinter & Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a button in a GUI and attach a function to it.

The function should include some code that duplicates a python file and pass some arguments to it.

Also, I want all of the created python files (after clicking the button) to be displayed in one window and arrange them using the built-in `.grid()` `tkinter` function.

Is this possible?

Comment: Mutating code like this is a pretty bad idea on the whole in general, and always necessary in Python. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create a count-down interface with the possibility to create many stand-alone counters in the same window. So the user can use a count down for many things at the same time. The target is to use one code multiply times ( the number of count downs the user needs) and the user chooses the number by adding more through the button.

Comment: Also, each count-down interface should be attached to specific tables in the DB so the user can have a log of what he have counted down for in the past (a history list)

Comment: NOTICE: The interfaces are meant to be permanently edited to the window, so when the user restarts the app, the interfaces remain there.

Comment: No need to mutate code for this - just instantiate and display a new set of widgets for each one, and persist the set of counters somehow - something as simple as a JSON file would work.

Comment: how can I instantiate and display a new set of widgets for each click by the user and permanently edit it to the app?

Comment: However you instantiate and display one counter, do it again!

Give it a.try, and maybe come back and ask further questions if you need to.

Comment: I instantiate and display the first counter by writing its code in a single py file. the only way to do that again is by writing the code again. do you think f.open(myfile.py, "x") and then f.write( the code) is a suitable option?

Comment: There's no point in mutating the code. Instead, mutate the data. You can read in a file and create timers for each piece of data in the file. This is how all programs work.

Comment: well, so you mean that I should use a JSON file instead to store the data, let's say a "name" for each timer, and then run a code on each name through a loop and this way it will guarantee running the code on all the data inside JSON whenever it is modified as well without having to write more code, did i get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to the comments I was able to figure out another way to achieve what I wanted.

I used a JSON file to store a list of data (different names). The data will be added to the JSON file through an entry field and a submit button.

Then a block of code will be executed for each name in a form of a loop. The code will display a set of widgets for each name and will be sorted using .pack().

NOTE: To prevent the widget functions from interrupting the other widgets mechanism (since it is a repeating of the same code), I have attached each name from the JSON file to the beginning of every variable.

So instead of auto-creating multiply python files to run a unique code for each set of widgets, JSON file, and a loop solved the issue

Comment: You don't need to open the same file twice inside `create()`.  Also this is not an answer, better edit your question to include this instead.